# How to request root permission for a particular operation android

Tags: android, root, su

I have an app that requires root access. I'm using the following code to request the permission:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

What this does is: when the user has granted the root access to the app, it displays the root sign (#) in the statusbar ( which is normal ). The symbol remains in the statusbar even after the app goes to the background or even after that activity is finished. **I want the symbol to appear when the permission is granted, and releasing the granted root access after performing the operation, so it removes the symbol from the statusbar.**

[HideItPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hideitpro&hl=en) does it so I know it's possible, but I couldn't find a way pf doing it. Can anyone help me how to do this ?

PS: I'm using [RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools) sdk for root operations.

Answer (score 0):

Android's permission system is different than traditional Linux.  On normal, commercial devices there is no access to "root" and there is no su command.  You have to have a rooted ROM for that functionality.

Comment: The app is for rooted devices only

Comment: That's an important detail.  Have you tried using the full path to the su binary?